# eBPF: 'bpf_map_update()' returns the 'invalid indirect read from stack' error

Tags: ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I have an eBPF program with the following map definitions:

```c
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") servers = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(struct ip_key),
    .value_size = sizeof(struct dest_info),
    .max_entries = MAX_SERVERS,
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") client_addrs = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(struct port_key),
    .value_size = sizeof(struct client_port_addr),
    .max_entries = MAX_CLIENTS,
};
```

where the struct definitions are as below:

```c
struct port_key {
    __u16 port;
    __u16 pad[3];
};

struct ip_key {
    __u32 key;
    __u32 pad;
};

struct dest_info {
    __u32 saddr;
    __u32 daddr;
    __u64 bytes;
    __u64 pkts;
    __u8 dmac[6];
    __u16 pad;
};

struct client_port_addr {
    __u32 client_ip;
    __u8 dmac[6];
    __u16 pad[3];
};
```

The program itself, after the pointer verifications and initial checks, is shown below.

```c
struct port_key key = {0};
struct client_port_addr val;
key.port = udp->source;
val.client_ip = iph->saddr;
memcpy (val.dmac, eth->h_source, 6 * sizeof(__u8));
bpf_map_update_elem(&client_addrs, &key, &val, BPF_ANY);
iph->saddr = IP_ADDRESS(BALANCER);
iph->daddr = dest_tnl->daddr;
memcpy (eth->h_source, eth->h_dest, 6 * sizeof(__u8));
memcpy (eth->h_dest, dest_tnl->dmac, 6 * sizeof(__u8));
```

So, the problem is that I use `bpf_map_update()` in my code, but while using it, I get the `invalid indirect read from the stack` error as shown below.

```
libbpf: 
0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: (61) r9 = *(u32 *)(r6 +4)
2: (61) r7 = *(u32 *)(r6 +0)
3: (18) r1 = 0xffffa59ac00b6000
5: (b7) r2 = 24
6: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6
 R1_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=50,imm=0) R2_w=inv24 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=0,imm=0) R9_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
last_idx 6 first_idx 0
regs=4 stack=0 before 5: (b7) r2 = 24
7: (b7) r8 = 1
8: (bf) r1 = r7
9: (07) r1 += 14
10: (2d) if r1 > r9 goto pc+130
 R0_w=inv(id=0) R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=14,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R8_w=inv1 R9_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
11: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r7 +12)
12: (71) r2 = *(u8 *)(r7 +13)
13: (67) r2 <<= 8
14: (4f) r2 |= r1
15: (b7) r8 = 2
16: (55) if r2 != 0x8 goto pc+124
 R0=inv(id=0) R1=inv(id=0,umax_value=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R2=inv8 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R8=inv2 R9=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
17: (61) r7 = *(u32 *)(r6 +4)
18: (61) r9 = *(u32 *)(r6 +0)
19: (bf) r6 = r9
20: (07) r6 += 14
21: (b7) r8 = 1
22: (2d) if r6 > r7 goto pc+118
 R0=inv(id=0) R1=inv(id=0,umax_value=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R2=inv8 R6_w=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=14,imm=0) R7_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8_w=inv1 R9_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R10=fp0
23: (bf) r1 = r9
24: (07) r1 += 34
25: (b7) r8 = 1
26: (2d) if r1 > r7 goto pc+114
 R0=inv(id=0) R1=pkt(id=0,off=34,r=34,imm=0) R2=inv8 R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=34,imm=0) R7=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8=inv1 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
27: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r6 +0)
28: (57) r1 &= 15
29: (b7) r8 = 1
30: (55) if r1 != 0x5 goto pc+110
 R0=inv(id=0) R1_w=inv5 R2=inv8 R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=34,imm=0) R7=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8_w=inv1 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
31: (61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r9 +26)
32: (18) r1 = 0xffffa59ac00b6018
34: (b7) r2 = 26
35: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6
 R0=inv(id=0) R1_w=map_value(id=0,off=24,ks=4,vs=50,imm=0) R2_w=inv26 R3_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=34,imm=0) R7=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8_w=inv1 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
last_idx 35 first_idx 26
regs=4 stack=0 before 34: (b7) r2 = 26
36: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r9 +20)
37: (57) r1 &= 65343
38: (b7) r8 = 1
39: (55) if r1 != 0x0 goto pc+101
 R0=inv(id=0) R1_w=inv0 R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=34,imm=0) R7=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8_w=inv1 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
40: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r9 +23)
41: (b7) r8 = 2
42: (55) if r1 != 0x11 goto pc+98
 R0=inv(id=0) R1_w=inv17 R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=34,imm=0) R7=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8_w=inv2 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
43: (bf) r1 = r9
44: (07) r1 += 42
45: (b7) r8 = 1
46: (2d) if r1 > r7 goto pc+94
 R0=inv(id=0) R1=pkt(id=0,off=42,r=42,imm=0) R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=42,imm=0) R7=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R8=inv1 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=42,imm=0) R10=fp0
47: (b7) r8 = 0
48: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -8) = r8
last_idx 48 first_idx 46
regs=100 stack=0 before 47: (b7) r8 = 0
49: (bf) r2 = r10
50: (07) r2 += -8
51: (18) r1 = 0xffff9a7bed1bc000
53: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
54: (bf) r7 = r0
55: (15) if r7 == 0x0 goto pc+85
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=8,vs=32,imm=0) R6=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=42,imm=0) R7=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=8,vs=32,imm=0) R8=invP0 R9=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=42,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmmmmmm
56: (b7) r8 = 0
57: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r8
last_idx 57 first_idx 55
regs=100 stack=0 before 56: (b7) r8 = 0
58: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r9 +34)
59: (6b) *(u16 *)(r10 -16) = r1
60: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r9 +26)
61: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -32) = r1
62: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r9 +11)
63: (73) *(u8 *)(r10 -23) = r1
64: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r9 +10)
65: (73) *(u8 *)(r10 -24) = r1
66: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r9 +7)
67: (67) r1 <<= 8
68: (71) r2 = *(u8 *)(r9 +6)
69: (4f) r1 |= r2
70: (71) r2 = *(u8 *)(r9 +9)
71: (67) r2 <<= 8
72: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r9 +8)
73: (4f) r2 |= r3
74: (67) r2 <<= 16
75: (4f) r2 |= r1
76: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -28) = r2
77: (bf) r2 = r10
78: (07) r2 += -16
79: (bf) r3 = r10
80: (07) r3 += -32
81: (18) r1 = 0xffff9a7bed1bf400
83: (b7) r4 = 0
84: (85) call bpf_map_update_elem#2
invalid indirect read from stack R3 off -32+10 size 16
processed 81 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 5 peak_states 5 mark_read 2

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'loadbal'
```

All of the defined structs for keys and values are padded to their next multiple of 8 bytes. Since I could not find any useful and descriptive explanation on my issue, explanations of this topic and maybe even a bit of detail are much appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Could you share the map definitions? It would also help a lot if you could provide a minimal reproducible example instead of this big program. It's not currently easy to know why `bpf_map_lookup_elem` is the issue.

Comment: Dear @pchaigno, my code consists of a main decision-making `if ... else ...` structure, towards the bottom, which I have minimalized by commenting out the branches that did not cause an error. Everything before `isFromServers = is_from_back_servers(iph->saddr);` is just in the verification and no functionality is included there. I also added the map and their struct definitions. Please see if this should help or something else is still required. Also, please note that the error is updated to `bpf_map_update_elem`. There was a little struct misuse I fixed yesterday.

Comment: If you can't produce a minimal reproducible example, could you at least share the full verifier logs and not just the end? It is not currently possible to understand the issue from the snippet of verifier logs.

Comment: I pruned all of the extra work for reaching the minimal reproducible example, and the above description is what I achieved. While doing it, I realized that the problem was that I had overlooked initializing the value struct in `bpf_map_update()`, which leaves us with some uninitialized bytes that the verifier does not feel comfortable with. Many thanks to @pchaigno. I also shared the full log of this minimal version for the record. I am only wondering, could there be any non-trivial reason for the misuse of `bpf_map_update()` other than the padding of the structs and uninitialized bytes?

Comment: Looks like not all fields in your `val` have been initialised before you tried to read from it when updating the map, because of the padding. Have you tried something like this before filling the struct?: `memset(&val, 0, sizeof(val))`. Or just copying 0s into `val.pad`

Comment: I agree with @Qeole. That's a common issue with BPF. Structures need to be explicitly zero-initialized if they have padding.

Comment: That is right. I initialized all of the struct to zero using `struct client_port_addr val = {0};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verifier complains because **your code is trying to read uninitialised data from the stack, in particular in your variable `val`**.

If we look at your code:

```c
struct client_port_addr {
    __u32 client_ip;
    __u8 dmac[6];
    __u16 pad[3];
};

struct client_port_addr val;
[...]
val.client_ip = iph->saddr;                                  // val.client_ip
memcpy (val.dmac, eth->h_source, 6 * sizeof(__u8));          // val.dmac
                                                             // val.pad where??
bpf_map_update_elem(&client_addrs, &key, &val, BPF_ANY);
```

You initialised `val.client_ip`, and `val.dmac`, but `val.pad` is never initialised. When you pass `val` to `bpf_map_update_elem()`, the eBPF verifier realises that the helper function might read this variable which contains uninitialised memory from kernel space. This is a security risk, therefore, the verifier rejects the program.

To fix the issue, **make sure you initialise the memory before using it**. You have at least three ways to do so:

- You could initialise `val` when declaring it, like for your `key`:

  ```c
  struct client_port_addr val = {0};
  ```

  This should work in your case, but is not generally recommended, because this will set all fields to 0 but if your struct contains padding that was not explicitely added, it may remain uninitialised.
- In your case, you could fill `val.pad` with zeroes with `memcpy()`. Same as the first option, this won't help if the compiler pads your struct.
- **The safest option would be to `memset()` the struct after declaring it**:

  ```c
  struct client_port_addr val;

  memset(&val, 0, sizeof(val));
  ```

  Then you can fill the relevant fields of the struct, and pass it to the map update helper.